# Bash: compare if a value is contained within an interval

Tags: bash, intervals

I got a text file which is tab separated and contains 2 columns like this:

```
1227637    1298347
1347879    1356788
1389993    1399847
...        ...
```

Now I got some values from an analysis and I'd like to check if these values are contained in my text file intervals.
For example if I have `1227659`, which is contained in the first interval, I'd like the bash-script to print to `std out` something like:

```
1227659 is contained between 1227637 and 1298347
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would use `awk` for this, not `bash` itself.

Comment: `awk` it's good too. Can you show me how?

Comment: Although it should be pretty easy with plain `bash`. `while read num1 num2; do ...; done < file`. Then use an `if` statement in the loop body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```sh
awk -v x=1227659 '
  $1<x && x<$2 {print x, "is contained between", $1, "and", $2}
' intervals.txt
```

```
1227659 is contained between 1227637 and 1298347
```

If you want any end of the interval to be interpreted as inclusive, change `<` to `<=` accordingly. If you want to  stop after the first match (makes only sense if the intervals can overlap), add `; exit` before the closing curly brace `}`.